# gltranslatef doesn't move all of my double int. array

Tags: lwjgl

I am working on a 2D platformer, and want the map to move (not too advanced, since I am only in "devstage 1") but when I apply the gltranslatef it doesn't move all textures, only the one in the top left corner.

this is the code, don't worry about other classes because they all work fine.

```
package Window;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

import controls.TileChanger;
import Functions.renderer;
import Window.GridHandler;

public class Main {



public static void main(String[] args) {    

    renderer.begin();

int[][] map = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
           {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 };

 GridHandler grid = new GridHandler(map);
 TileChanger changer = new TileChanger(grid);

    float translate_x = 0;
    float translate_y = 0;
    int speed = 5;

    while(!Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_Q)) {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glPushMatrix();

        glTranslatef(translate_x, translate_y, 0);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
            translate_x += speed;
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
            translate_x -= speed;
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
            translate_y += speed;
        }

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
            translate_y -= speed;
        }



        changer.Update();

        grid.draw();

        glPopMatrix();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }
    Display.destroy();
    System.exit(0);


}
}
```

can someone show me how I can apply the gltranslatef to all of the map[][]?
thank you.

Comment: `glPushMatrix`, `glTranslatef` and `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` belong to deprecated OpenGL, don't use that. Follow some tutorials about matrices and textures

Comment: I use LWJGL 2  by the way

Comment: The glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) works fine for me, when I disable it it doesn't render a texture